# Rest Assured - retry request if failed

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, rest-assured

Example Test:

```
@Test
public void shouldGetRoutesList() {
    Response response =
            given()
                    .headers("RequestId", 10)
                    .headers("Authorization", accessToken)
                    .contentType(ContentType.JSON).
            expect()
                    .statusCode(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK).
            when()
                    .get("address");
    String responseBody = response.getBody().asString();
    System.out.println(responseBody);
    logger.info("Log message");
}
```

Thing is that sometimes response from service equals 500 error. It's because of application error and it's application fault so I would like to add temp. workaround to retry `.get` if service returns 500. I was thinking about `if` or `do-while` but I know that it's not very clever way. Anyone could advice some solution ?

In another words - I want to retry whole test (or just .get) if statusCode=!HTTP_OK

Comment: If you want to retry something loop is your only way. And what's wrong with simple "not clever" solution?

Comment: I could remove expect() to not fail test because of statusCode=500 and in IF statement check that this code is/or is not   visible. But another issue is that responseBody do not return status code as a String so I can't just do something like responseBody.contains("500") ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TestNG, than you can implement your own retryAnalyzer:
http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/retry-failed-tests-testng/

In case of other frameworks the "not very clever" solutions are your answers, catch the exception and try again until exit criteria matches.

Unfortunately RestAssured has not mechanism to retry.

Comment: A simple loop could solve the problem. But, what if I want to keep retrying until certain conditions are achieved. Ex. myRequestObject.doRetry(3times, with 5sec pause, until responseCode=200 AND responseBody.message.status ="success") ?

Comment: Than use these conditions as exit crieria in a while loop for instance.



'while(numOfAttempt <= 3 && respCode != 200 && !message.equal("success")) {
    do the request...
    save the respCode and message;
    numOfAttemp++;
}'

Answer (score 0):

You can also use SpringRetry library and RetryTemplate class.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Dev.Failsafe library.  They have a RetryPolicy class that works great with RestAssured.  This video covers it well:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwY4VP3lQ7I

Answer (score 0):

To enable retry mechanism make use of [awaitility](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility) library.

This [blog](https://medium.com/@aswathyn/awaitility-handling-async-wait-in-automation-5066e20a1d12) has good examples.

```
@Test
public void waitTest() throws Exception {
    Awaitility.await().atMost(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).until(() -> this.getStatusCode() == 200)
}

public int getStatusCode() {
    return given()
        .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
        .get('testapiurl')
        .then()
        .extract()
        .statusCode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you're required is just to get some particular status code and it isn't in the testing scope, use plain old `do/while` like:

```
int counter = 0;
int statusCode = 200;
Response response;
do {
  if (counter > 0) {
    try {
      log.severe(String.format("the previous request failed with the '%s' status code - holding runtime for 1 second and retrying", statusCode));
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
  response = given()
      .spec(getSomeSpec())
      .queryParams(queryParams)
      .get();
  statusCode = response.statusCode();
  counter += 1;
} while (statusCode != 200 && counter <= 2);
```